# Springboot obtaining object from thymeleaf option

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

So I am trying to create a new Product object with Springboot and Thymeleaf. I am passing in a List of categories into thymeleaf and displaying them in a option selection to be selected when the object is created. The issue is that the object is being created but the category is null and I am not sure why.

This is my products instance variables

```
public class Product {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name, description;
    private double price;
    private Binary image;
    private Category category;
    private ProductStatus status;

    public Product() {

    }
```

It has a instance variable for Category.

```
@Document(collection = "categories")
public class Category {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name, description;

    public Category() {

    }
```

This is the thymeleaf code for the creation of the Product option where category is held.
 `<form method="post" th:action="@{/products/add}" th:object="${product}" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

and the controller
`m.addObject("product", new Product());`

```
                            <div class="input-group mb-6">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text">Product Category</span>
                                </div>
                                <select th:field="*{category}">
                                    <option th:each="cat : ${categories}"
                                            th:value="${cat}"
                                            th:text="${cat.getName()}">Wireframe</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I have a POST button that executes in the product/add
this is the rest API end point for it

```
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/products/add"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addProduct(ModelAndView m, @Valid Product product, MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        User admin = userRepository.findByEmail(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal().toString());
        System.out.println("cat: " + product.getCategory().getName());
```

It takes in a @Valid Product product
when I try to print out the category name which i selected I get an NPE.

I am trying to obtain the category selected from the option `th:value="${cat}"`
but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer. Change `th:value="${cat}"` to `th:value="${cat.id}"` in `<option>`. The reason is you are assigning the reference value of category object in `th:value="${cat}"` which will no longer exists in memory. Since spring will automatically convert the id to respective object, we just have to assign id to value. `category=1` will be converted to `new Category()` with `id=1`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the object to the model and view:

```
modelAndView.getModelMap().addAttribute("dto", dto);
```

and get it in the thymeleaf side, for example:

```
<form th:action="@{/url}" th:object="${dto}" th:method="post">
    <input type="date" th:field="${dto.date}">
```

Then you can recieve the filled object in the /url endpoint with:

```
@Valid DtoClass dtoClass
```

Comment: Encapsulating the form i do have this.  <form method="post" th:action="@{/products/add}" th:object="${product}" enctype="multipart/form-data"> and in the controller i have this m.addObject("product", new Product());

Comment: use modelAndView.getModelMap().addAttribute(